Use nameof() to an element of a List of object
I have a model class:
public class TblStudent 
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public string? StuID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string? StuFullName { get; set; }
}

I also have a view model class:
public class StudentIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<TblStudent> StuTable { get; set; } = new List<TblStudent>();
{

In my view, I'm trying to get the property name from TblStudent using this code:
@(nameof(Model.StuTable.FirstOrDefault().StuFullName))

however, I get an error:

Sub-expression cannot be used in an argument to nameof

How to display just the property name of the StuFullName property in this case where it's a list?

@(nameof(<namespace of TblStudent>.TblStudent.StuFullName)) ?

nameof is evaluated at compile-time, therefore function calls (a.o.) are not possible.

As mentioned in the comment, you get the property name from your desired entity as below:
@(nameof(<namespace of TblStudent>.TblStudent.StuFullName))

Otherwise, you need to work with the HtmlHelper.LabelFor method.
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.StuTable.FirstOrDefault().StuFullName)

Note that, this approach will display the value from the DisplayAttribute you applied to the property. When the DisplayAttribute is not applied to the property, it will display the property name. So if you consider this approach, you need to remove the DisplayAttribute from the property.
If you want to iterate each element in Model.StuTable, you can do as below:
foreach (var stud in Model.StuTable)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => stud.StuFullName)
}

